# Flowable runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey('MY_SUBPROCESS_KEY') executes but superProcessId null

Tags: javascript, java, bpmn, flowable

After starting from my MY_SUPER_PROCESS another subprocess using the following syntax:

```
 runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey('MY_SUBPROCESS_KEY')
```

the subprocess is started and executed correctly, but in the admin panel flowable panel there is no subprocess visible for MY_SUPER_PROCESS. Also asking about 'MY_SUBPROCESS_KEY' instance returns that superProcessInstanceId is null.

Is there any possibility to start the subprocess so that the information about super process and subprocess connection won't be lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to run the process via runtimeService? Try using [callActivity](https://flowable.com/open-source/docs/bpmn/ch07b-BPMN-Constructs/#call-activity-sub-process).

**UPD:**

For start multi instance of subprocess in loop can use callActivity with [Multi-instance](https://flowable.com/open-source/docs/bpmn/ch07b-BPMN-Constructs/#multi-instance-for-each) marker.

Comment: I need to start a subprocess in a loop, while number of loops is undefined. So I need something like for (int i=0; i<SOME=NUMBER; I++)  runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey('MY_SUBPROCESS_KEY')

Comment: Then maybe this [Multi-instance (for each)](https://flowable.com/open-source/docs/bpmn/ch07b-BPMN-Constructs/#multi-instance-for-each)?

Comment: this one looks good. you could update your answer then I would accept it. I need to check how to set variables for each loop and pass the number of loops, but this should be described in the documentation I guess.